# Bold square brackets

Tags: math-mode, symbols, bold

How do I typeset a bold square bracket? I need to typeset it about 3 times thicker than it is (to denote a specific mathematical operator). `{\bf[}` does not do this. Things like `[\![` do not seem to produce good quality. "The Comprehensive LaTeX Symbol List" does not seem to mention an appropriate symbol.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`\usepackage{bm}` and then `\bm{[}`. Maybe this isn't bold enough for you in which case you can use a font with a heavy variant (eg the commercial mathtime set) and `\usepackage{mathtime,bm}` and then `\hm{[}`.

Otherwise maybe you can use a different symbol, such as double square bracket `\llbracket` from `\usepackage{stmaryrd}`.

Answer (score -1):

Try using `{\textbf [}` and `{\textbf ]}`.